# How to reference cells in other workbooks using a variable in the address

Tags: excel, vba

I need to use a variable in the cell addresses on two workbooks.  This is how am getting started.

I'm checking the cells in column AE on the active workbook against the cells in column T on the master sheet and if there is a match I want to put a 1 in column T on that same row on the master sheet.

```
For x = 2 to 1000
   If AE("X") = Workbooks(master.xlsx).I("X") Then Workbooks(master.xlsx).T("x"), 1, 0
Next x
```

Comment: This is not really a propper vba code to start with. Your IF statement is not written correctly. Also you don't define a worksheet within your master workbook. Thirdly you should use Cells() instead of AE("X").

Comment: You should really take some basic tour/tutorial about VBA syntax and how to start learning VBA.

Answer (score 1):

When using VBA in Excel you have to remember that code is stupid - you need to explain exactly where everything is each time you want to reference it.

So, `AE("X")` can be translated by a human based on your descriptive text and looking at the rest of the code.  VBA on the other hand will look at `AE`, realise it's not a codeword but is followed by brackets so will think it's some kind of array that hasn't been declared and start throwing all kinds of errors.

So, `AE("X")` is a cell in column `AE` on row `X` in a named worksheet in a named workbook in the Excel application.  VBA knows something!  It knows it's in Excel so we don't have to tell it each time - we have to tell it everything else though otherwise it starts making assumptions and generally gets it wrong.

So....
Your workbook is `"Master.xlsx"`.  This is a different workbook than the one the code is sitting in - it has an `xlsx` extension so can't contain any VBA code.  The workbook is also open, otherwise you'd need to use the full path of the workbook and tell it to open it.

This code declares a variable called `wrkBk` and then sets it to reference the `Master.xlsx` workbook.  As the file name is a string of text characters we need to place it within quotation marks.  Now, whenever we need to reference the workbook we can just use `wrkBk`.

```
Dim wrkBk As Workbook
Set wrkBk = Workbooks("Master.xlsx")
```

If the workbook is closed you'd use
`Set wrkBk = Workbooks.Open("<full path to workbook>\Master.xlsx")`
There's a few special keywords you can use in place of `Workbooks` to reference specific open workbooks: `Set wrkBk = ThisWorkbook` will reference the workbook that your VBA code is in, `Set wrkBk = ActiveWorkbook` will reference whichever workbook is currently active.

The next step is to reference the correct worksheet within the workbook.  We know the worksheet is going to be in the `Master.xlsx` workbook so that needs referencing - if we don't then the code will assume we mean whichever workbook is active when the code executes.  Now, whenever we use `wrkSht` the code will know we mean `Sheet1` that is in the `Master.xlsx` workbook (we don't use `wrkBk.wrkSht` as `wrkSht` already knows about `wrkBk`).

```
Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
Set wrkSht = wrkBk.Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

Right, now we're ready to reference the cells within the workbook.  There's a number of ways to reference a cell - it's a `Range` of cells, so you could use `wrkSht.Range("A1")` for instance, it's also a cell on it's own, so you could use `wrkSht.Cells(1,1)` which means the cell at position row 1 and column 1, you could even use `wrksht.Range(wrksht.Cells(1,1), wrksht.Cells(5,1))` which means a range of cells from row 1, column 1 to row 5, column 1.  This could also be written as `wrksht.Range("A1:A5")`.  Note - before each reference to a cell I'm telling it which sheet the cell is on.

Now, onto your loop and using `X` to reference the cell.
`For x = 2 To 1000: Next x`.  That'll work and increase the value held by `x`.
You want to look at column `AE` - column 31 in numerical terms.
`wrksht.Range("x")` won't work as it will look at the literal string "x" and not the number that it stands for - the code also doesn't mention the column.
So `wrkSht.Cells(x,31)`.  There's no quotes around the `x`  This will reference cells `AE2`, `AE3`, `AE4`, etc as your loop continues.

Finally, placing values in a cell - in plain English it's basically saying *the value of referenced cell equals this value I'm giving it*, or in VBA `wrkSht.Cells(31,x) = 1`

Your final code, with correct references set would like similar to this:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim wrkBk As Workbook
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Dim x As Long

    'Set reference to external workbook.
    Set wrkBk = Workbooks("Master.xlsx")
    Set wrkSht = wrkBk.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    For x = 2 To 1000
        'I haven't used variables here - just referenced the correct cells within the ActiveWorkbook.
        'You may find it better to use ThisWorkbook instead.

        'This is an IF...END IF block which allows you write multiple lines of code for each condition.
        'For one line you could combine the first two lines in the block - but you wouldn't have the ELSE condition.
        If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 31) = wrkSht.Cells(x, 9) Then
            wrkSht.Cells(x, 20) = 1
        Else
            wrkSht.Cells(x, 20) = 0
        End If
    Next x

End Sub
```

Hope that wasn't too wordy... started losing my way halfway through. :)

Comment: got a run-time error "9"   subscript out of range at the first set line

Comment: Is `Master.xlsx` open when you start the procedure? If not you'll need to use `Set wrkBk = Workbooks.Open("<full path to workbook>\Master.xlsx")`

Comment: yes  there are three workbooks open...  1 named control that contains the macros...  the master.xlsx and a new file that could be any name because it is the active that contains the AE column and we are looking for that information in the master sheet...  if we find a match that record is removed manually.

Comment: well you were right... the problem the master sheet was save as an .xlsm and its sheet1 was not named sheet1 because it was originally a .csv.  so when all the names are right every thing works..   thanks